# ウィンドウズフォームアプリケーションから対話型コンソールアプリケーションを操作するには？

Tags: windows, .net, visual-studio, vb.net

初めての投稿になります。

表題の通りなのですがウィンドウズフォームアプリケーション（環境　Win7,.NetFramework4.0 or 4.5）で本来DOSプロンプトで動作するプログラム、例えばMySQL.exeなどをにコマンドを送り、その表示結果を取得する事は可能でしょうか？

具体性の乏しい質問なので恐縮ですが解決方法についてまったく想像がつかない状態ですのでザクっとした方向性でも良いのでご示唆頂けないでしょうか？

Consoleのようなプログラム（http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/?source=typ_redirect）を組めば良いのだと想像しますが可能であれば.Netで構築したいと考えております。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず.NETで外部プロセスを起動する場合`System.Diagnostics.Process`型を使用します。

```
Dim p As new Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = "mysql.exe"
p.Start()
```

この際にプロセスにパラメーターを渡す手段としては2つの方法があります。1個はコマンドライン引数です。

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "hoge fuga"
p.Start()
```

これはコマンドプロンプトで`mysql.exe hoge fuga`と入力した場合と同等の動作となります。

またコマンドライン引数ではなく、起動後に入力を求められるタイプのプロセスとは標準入力で通信します。

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
p.Start()
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("hoge fuga")
```

なおプロセスからの出力は`StandardOutput`や`StandardError`で読み取れます。

Comment: pgrhoさま  
○早速の回答ありがとうございました。
以下のようにコードを組んでみましたが標準出力が上手くつかめません。
想定ではデータベースの一覧が取れる筈だと思っているのですが…  
  
`Dim command As String = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"`  
`Dim p As New Process()`  
`p.StartInfo.FileName = command`  
`p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False`  
`p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True`  
`p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True`  
`p.Start()`  
`p.StandardInput.WriteLine("show database;" + "\r\n")`  
`Dim output As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`  
`MsgBox(output)`

Comment: 半角スペース2個入れたのに改行しなかったです。
すみません。

もうひとつ疑問があります。

上記のようなコードではコマンドがハードコーディングされてしまっていますが、例えばユーザーがテキストボックスに入れたコマンドに応じて動的に出力を取りたい場合は上記プロセスを起動しておいて、テキストボックスからこのプロセスに割り込ませるようなイメージで良いのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
MySQL.exeに関しては動作確認がとれました。
多少変な動きもしますが･･･
こちらでもう少し整理して再度質問しなおします。

Comment: @Peinyan そのあたりは実装されているアプリケーションの仕様次第なのですが、方向性としてはプライベート変数に`Process`を保持してイベント毎に`StandardInput.WriteLine'`と`StandardOutput.ReadLine`を実行するイメージになるかと思います。ただこのようなプログラムは複雑になりがちなのでMySQLに限って言えば`Process`ではなく`MySqlConnection`で実装できないか検討したほうが良いでしょうね。

Comment: @ pgrho　丁寧なフォローアップありがとうございます。　　.NETのフォーム上でコマンドプロンプトライクな物が出来ればと思い色々格闘してみました。　　現状デバッグモードで確認したら'StandardInp‌​ut.WriteLine'と'StandardOutput.ReadLine'が終わるとプロセスが落ちているのです。　コマンドプロンプトの様に「ユーザーが入力して結果を確認して更に入力する」場合プロセスが落ちてしまうと意味がなくなるような気がします。　　プライベート変数に'Process'を保持する事はその部分の解決策になるかも知れないと言うご示唆であると理解してもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @Peinyan 「ユーザーに一項目ずつ入力させるタイプのコマンドライン等で1個のイベントで処理が終わらない場合、ローカルではなくフォームに変数を持たせる必要がある」という意味です。プロセスの終了については`HasExited`や`WaitForExit`で対応することになりますね。なお余談ですが、異常終了よりもプロセスが想定外に終了しないことの方が有害ですので確実に`Kill`する処理を入れたほうが良いですよ。

Comment: @ pgrho　ありがとうございます。頂いたヒントを元にやってみます。