# ウィンドウズフォームアプリケーションから対話型コンソールアプリケーションを操作する為の実装について

Tags: .net, vb.net

※環境　Win764Bit,　.NetFramework4.0 or 4.5

本来DOSプロンプトで動作する対話型プログラム、例えばMySQL.exeなどをにコマンドを送り、その表示結果を取得するウィンドウズフォームアプリケーションを作成しています。

動作イメージは添付の画像のような感じで、テキストボックスにコマンドを入力し、送信ボタンを押すことを繰り返す事で作業を進めます。

※入力されているテキストはイメージです。
[image: アプリケーションイメージ]

これを実現するために以前質問した内容（[ウィンドウズフォームアプリケーションから対話型コンソールアプリケーションを操作するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12663/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%82%BA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%AF%BE%E8%A9%B1%E5%9E%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)）を踏まえて作成してみたのですが上手く行きません。

主な処理概要として、

１．フォームをロードするタイミング（Loadイベント）で`System.Diagnostics.Process`で対象となるコンソールアプリケーション（mysql.exe）のプロセスを立ち上げ、プロセス自体はフォームの変数へ保持しておく。

２．送信ボタンを押すとフォームに保持してあるプロセスに対して`StandardInp‌​ut.WriteLine`と`StandardOutput.ReadLine`で入出力を行いその結果を結果領域に表示します。

この時`StandardInp‌​ut.WriteLine`でコマンドを送出した瞬間にプロセスが終了していまい、結果を受け取ることは可能なのですがその後の操作が継続して行う事が出来ません。

プロセスが終了しなければ良いと思い`WaitForExit`を試してみましたが同期待機なので画面がフリーズして使えませんでした。

非同期で待機が可能な`Process.Exited`も試しましたが`StandardInp‌​ut.WriteLine`処理でプロセスが終了してしまう事には変わりがありませんでした。

なんとかプロセスが終了せず継続してコンソールアプリケーションと対話を続ける方法はないものでしょうか？

なるべく.NETでの実現を望んでいますがインターフェイスだけ.NETであればいいので他の言語などでの実現方式もあればヒントを頂ければ嬉しいです。

前回@pgrho様に丁寧に教えて頂いたのですが当方の理解が足りず再度の質問となります。

皆様のお力添えを頂ければと思います。

なにとぞよろしくお願いします。

以下検証中のプログラムコードです。

```vb
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class Form1

    Private p As New Process

    Private Sub p_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'プロセスが終了したときに実行される
        MessageBox.Show("終了しました。")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        '起動するファイルを指定する
        Dim command As String = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"

        p.StartInfo.FileName = command
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        p.SynchronizingObject = Me

        AddHandler p.Exited, New EventHandler(AddressOf p_Exited)
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        p.Start()


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("show databases;" + "\r\n")
        Dim output As String = p.StandardOutput.Read()
        Dim errorStrings As String = p.StandardError.Read()
        MsgBox(output + errorStrings)
    End Sub
End Class
```

○プロセス終了
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: プロセスが終了してしまうというのは本当でしょうか。それをどうやって確認しましたか？ 出力の読み込みは実際にはBeginOutputReadLineを使ったり、読み込みループを別スレッドで行ったりして非同期で行う必要があると思いますが、そのあたりの記述がないことから、単にReadLineを同期的に実行（ループ？）→そこで次の出力待ちでブロックされている、というだけではないのかと推測したりもします。実際のコードを示していただくことが早道かと思います。

Comment: @Ripple さま　　コメント有難うございます。 プロセス終了の判断はデバッグのステップ毎の実行でp.StandardInput.WriteLine("show databases;" + "\r\n")実行の次で変数p（プロセスが入ってる）をウォッチした結果です。

プログラムコードも追加しておきました。

Comment: 変数pをウォッチして、何がどうなっていたからプロセスが終了したと思いましたか。

Comment: @Ripple さま　丁寧なフォローありがとうございます。　回答の方も重ねてお礼申し上げます。　プロセスの件、取り急ぎ画像をアップいたしました。　回答の方も手が空き次第熟読させていただきます。

Comment: なるほど。mysqlはよくわかりませんが`\r\n`が悪さをしてる可能性はないでしょうか。

Comment: ちょっと調べたところでは`\r`は再接続コマンド、`\n`は未定義のようですね。`\r\n`が解釈できずに落ちてる・・・？それくらいで落ちることはない気もしますが・・・

Comment: ExitCodeが1なので異常終了したのは間違いなさそうです。

Comment: @Ripple さま 異常終了の件は「\r\n」に原因が有る事間違いないと思います。
まず、MySQL.exeをプロセス起動した後”show databases;” でボタンを押すと何も結果が返ってきません。　次に再起動しなおして”show databases;　\r\n”とするとデータベースの一覧とシンタックスエラーが出力されて現在フォームと一緒に表示するようにしてあるDOS窓が落ちます。　また他のプログラム（R.exe）などもシンタックスエラーやオブジェクトノットファウンドなどのよくあるエラーでDOS窓が落ちる事を確認しました。　これらのプログラムを普通にコマンドプロンプトから実行してエラーを出力してもプロセスが落ちる事はありませんでした。

Comment: @Ripple さま　プロセス変数pのmainmodule, module両プロパティに「Modules {"32 ビット プロセスは、64 ビット プロセスのモジュールにアクセスできません。"} System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception」と言うメッセージが残っていました。　これが原因でしょうか？

Comment: 状況がよくわかりません。1)私の回答のコードを試したということでしょうか。2) *何も結果が返ってきません。* というのはどうなることを表していますか。フリーズする、イベントが上がってこない、イベントは来るが文字列が空、など。

Comment: @Ripple さま　大変失礼しました。　1)おっしゃる通り回答コードを試してみた結果です。　2）ボタンを押す事が可能なのでフリーズではないと思いますがテキストボックスになんの‌​文字列も返ってこない状況です。　show databases;を4回入力した後　\r\nを入力すると4回分のデータベース一覧とエラーがテキストボックスに出力されて、プロセスが落ちる事から見るとエラーが出るまで（プロセスが落ちるまで）イベントとして上がってきてはいるがテキス‌​トボックスに入ってこないように見受けられます。

Comment: いえ、私の追試ではイベントが上がってきていません。（イベントハンドラの中のAppendTextの行にブレークポイントを貼れば検証できます。）mysqlが出力をバッファリングしているためです。回答に追記したのはその対処ですので、試していただいて報告してもらえると助かります。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p.StandardOutput.Read`(および`ReadLine`)メソッドは実際に入力(外部プロセスから見れば出力)があるまで現在のスレッドをブロックしてしまうので、フォームアプリ等のメインスレッドで使用してはいけません。

非同期に読み込みを行うには`ReadAsync`メソッドを使ったり、別スレッドを起こして`Read`/`ReadLine`したりといった方法がありますが、手軽なのは`BeginOutputReadLine`を使ってイベントとして入力を受け取ることかと思います。

とりあえず下記コードで入出力はできることは確認しました。

それと、VB.NETにおいて`"\r\n"`は改行コードを意味しません。文字通り`\r\n`という文字列を書き込んでいるだけになってますのでそこも修正しています。

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    '起動するファイルを指定する
    Dim command As String = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"

    p.StartInfo.FileName = command
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    p.SynchronizingObject = Me

    ' 標準出力、標準エラーを受け取るとテキストボックスに追加する。
    AddHandler Me.p.OutputDataReceived,
        Sub(s, dataReceivedEvent)
            Me.TextBox1.AppendText(dataReceivedEvent.Data & Environment.NewLine)
        End Sub
    AddHandler Me.p.ErrorDataReceived,
        Sub(s, dataReceivedEvent)
            Me.TextBox1.AppendText(dataReceivedEvent.Data & Environment.NewLine)
        End Sub

    p.Start()
    p.BeginOutputReadLine()
    p.BeginErrorReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("show databases;")
End Sub
```

---

一般的には上記のコードで他のプロセスと入出力ができます。
質問では「例えばMySQLなど」となっていたので、一般的な回答としてはここまでです。

**MySQLについて**

mysqlコマンドは出力がリダイレクトされると動きが変わります。出力を最適化するため、出力先がコンソールかどうか判断してわざわざ動きを変えているようです。

とりあえずわかった範囲でmysqlの現象と対処法です。

- 出力がバッファリングされる
  `--unbuffered`オプションをつけて起動すれば即フラッシュされるようになります。
- テーブルなどの出力時に罫線フォーマットされない
  `--table`オプションをつければ罫線つきになります。
- `\r`コマンドなどのエラー時にプロセスが終了してしまう？
  これは解決方法が見つかりませんでした。

ひとまず`p.Start()`の前に

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-uuser -ppass --unbuffered --table"
```

のようにすればそれっぽく動きます。

参考：
[Super User: Different output when redirecting](https://superuser.com/questions/352490/different-output-when-redirecting)
[Stack Overflow: A bit curious about `mysql -e` output format with & without redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812190/a-bit-curious-about-mysql-e-output-format-with-without-redirect)
[GitHubGist: bashでパイプとかでつないでバッファされちゃう時](https://gist.github.com/riywo/874011)

Comment: @Peinyan 質問のコメントに書かれた事象はmysql側の問題です。とりあえず対処法を追記しました。これ以上はmysqlの問題となると思うので、mysqlが興味の対象なのであれば別の質問としたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。　当方の環境でも動作確認とれました。　現在の問題は個々のコンソールアプリケーションの問題である事が理解できましたので本件を以上でクローズさせて頂きたく思います。